# How has this derivation been achieved?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

This is a step in a derivation I am to know, but I can't figure out how to achieve it - specifically, how we end up with $1 + e^{-X\theta}$ instead of $1 + e^{X\theta}$ as the denominator in the applicable terms. Working it through I seem to get the latter.

These steps are given in the literature, not derived by me:

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\left[-y\log(1 + e^{-X\theta}) + (1 - y)\left[-X\theta - \log(1 + e^{-X\theta})\right]\right]$$

$$= -y\left(\frac{-X}{1 + e^{-X\theta}}\right) + (1 - y)\left(-X - \frac{-X}{1 + e^{-X\theta}}\right)$$

(see http://cl.ly/image/2o2R1P1d290u for all steps)

To offer some context factoring out $-X$ would leave in the first term, for example, $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-X\theta}}$ which is the sigmoid function, and this is indeed what is required for the subsequent steps.

I suppose my problem must lie in my calculation:

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\theta}\left(-y\log(1 + e^{-X\theta})\right) = -y\frac{-X\frac{1}{e^{X\theta}}}{1 + e^{-X\theta}} = -y\frac{-X}{1 + e^{X\theta}}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a difficult derivative to take. It has been verified by two users now. You can also check with Sage or WolframAlpha, etc. If the computation "in the literature" disagrees, it is wrong.

Comment: I appreciate your patience, and I indeed agree with your answers - alas I need to know the derivation for an exam soon, and as it doesn't appear to agree with the sample answer I am naturally concerned. In case I am being thick here, this does suggest that the derivative is not (a product of) the sigmoid function, as this literature suggests?

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/2o2R1P1d290u

Comment: Thanks. The computation in the screenshot appears to contain an error between lines 4 and 5. The correct final answer can still be written in terms of the [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function): replace $\operatorname{sigmoid}(X\theta)$ with $\operatorname{sigmoid}(-X\theta)$ in the last line of the screenshot.

Comment: Ah, of course you can yes. Wonderful, I'm glad it's not dodgy differentiation on my part - thanks for bearing with me there, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $1+e^{-X\theta}$ inside of logarithm. After derivative is taken, the content of the logarithm moves into denominator, because $\frac{d}{du}\log u=\frac{1}{u}$. You also get the derivative of $1+e^{-X\theta}$ in the numerator (chain rule), which is $-X\,e^{-X\theta}$. So,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[-y \log(1 + e^{-X\theta})\right]
=-y \frac{-X\,e^{-X\theta}}{1 + e^{-X\theta}}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[ (1 - y)\left[-X\theta - \log(1 + e^{-X\theta})\right]\right] =
(1 - y)\left\{-X -\frac{-X\,e^{-X\theta}}{1 + e^{-X\theta}}\right\}
$$ 
One can then simplify a bit, using 
$$
\frac{-X\,e^{-X\theta}}{1 + e^{-X\theta}} = \frac{-X }{ e^{X\theta}+1}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though the denominator is $e^{X\theta} + 1$  rather than $e^{-X\theta} + 1$? Just to clarify in case, the two steps in my question are given in the literature, rather than derived by me.

Comment: @jstephenson The denominator is $e^{-X\theta}+1$ at first, and then it becomes $e^{X\theta}+1$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first term
$$\frac d{d\theta}\bigg(-y\log(1 + e^{-X\theta})\bigg)=-y\frac d{d\theta}\bigg(\log(1 + e^{-X\theta})\bigg)=-y\frac 1{1+e^{-X\theta}}\frac d{d\theta}\bigg(1 + e^{-X\theta}\bigg)$$

$$=-y\frac {e^{-X\theta}}{1+e^{-X\theta}}\frac d{d\theta}\bigg(-X\theta\bigg)=-y\frac {-Xe^{-X\theta}}{1+e^{-X\theta}}$$
and some manipulation
$$-y\frac {-Xe^{-X\theta}}{1+e^{-X\theta}}=-y\frac {-X}{\big(1+e^{-X\theta}\big)e^{X\theta}}=-y\frac {-X}{e^{X\theta}+1}$$

Comment: Thanks. As in my comment on the above answer, though, surely $\frac{-X}{e^{X\theta} + 1} \neq \frac{-X}{1 + e^{-X\theta}}$, which is what the literature's derivation has?